# In Javascript can I add dynamic property to another dynamic property using Object.defineProperty

Tags: jquery

I have dynamic property which contains array. For that array property I need another dynamic property "Count" which is actually a length of the array.

```
Object.defineProperty( this, 
        'ObjectVersions': {
            get: function () {
                return globalObjects.CurrentItems;
            }
        }
```

I want to access like **Items.ObjectVersions.Count**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

```
'ObjectVersions': {
            get: function () {
                var result = globalObjects.CurrentItems;
                result.Count = globalObjects.CurrentItems.length;
                return result;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This would help:

```
Object.defineProperty( this, 
    'ObjectVersions': {
        get: function () {
            return globalObjects.CurrentItems;
        },
        Count : globalObjects.CurrentItems.length
     }
);
```

My be we should also update the value of `Count` every time we have objects added or removed from `globalObjects.CurrentItems`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion ikken . I have tried this already and not working. I also tried like Count : { return globalObjects.CurrentItems.length } and this is also not working

Comment: My be we should update the value of `Count` every time we have objects added or removed from `globalObjects.CurrentItems`

Answer (score 0):

*I have dynamic property which contains array. For that array property I need another dynamic property "Count" which is actually a length of the array.*

What is the use of it, as arrays already have a length property. Which can be used at anytime in a code where you are going to use that particular array.

Comment: It is a tool extended using javascript for windows. In windows it is already implemented with Count property. Now I am changing it like work for both windows and web. So I need Count property instead of length property.